# In Kivy.kv file how do I reference a method in another class

Tags: python, class, kivy

I'm having difficulties understanding the relationship between kivy.kv files and class.
I've coded a simple app with two classes, Test3App & Restore, with two Buttons and a Label.
On clicking the Restore button I get error:
AttributeError: 'Test3App' object has no attribute 'Restore'.
My question is: How do I reference the Restore class in the kv or python files?

test3.py

```
from kivy.app import App

class Test3App(App): 

    def enlarge_text(self):
        if self.root.ids.label.font_size <90:
            self.root.ids.label.font_size += 16
        else:
            self.root.ids.but1.text = ' font_size at\n[b][size=20]Maximum'
            self.root.ids.but1.color = 'yellow'

class Restore():

    def font_size_reset(self):
        self.root.ids.label.font_size = 16
        self.root.ids.but1.text = 'font_size\nEnlarge'
        self.root.ids.but1.color = 'white'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test3App().run()
```

test3.kv

```
BoxLayout:

    Button:
        id: but1
        text: 'font_size\nEnlarge'
        on_press: app.enlarge_text()
        markup: True
  
    Button:
        text: 'font_size\nRestore'
        on_press: app.Restore.font_size_reset() 
  
    Label:
        id: label
        font_size: 16
        text: str(int(label.font_size))
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why can't you just put your `font_size_reset` method to the `Test3App` instead?

Comment: I could & have but I'm trying to understand the relationship of class and the kv file and thought someone could put me on the right path.

Comment: Alright cool, so I have another question to ask: Does the `Restore` class have anything to do, or at least appear anywhere inside your .kv file?

Comment: Restore class is not in the kv file. At present its sole purpose is to reset the font_size.
What I'm trying to understand is how to reference attributes(methods/variables) in one class to those in another class.
I assume that I need to make a reference to the Restore class either in the python or kv scripts to create a link, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you would have an instance of `Restore` somewhere in your app, and you would reference that instance in your `kv`. Here is one way to access the `font_size_reset()` method in your `kv`:

```
#: import Restore test3.Restore
BoxLayout:

    Button:
        id: but1
        text: 'font_size\nEnlarge'
        on_press: app.enlarge_text()
        markup: True

    Button:
        text: 'font_size\nRestore'
        on_press: Restore.font_size_reset('Abba')

    Label:
        id: label
        font_size: 16
        text: str(int(label.font_size))
```

The `import` makes the `Restore` class available in the `kv`. The call to `font_size_reset()` provides a meaningless argument since that method requires a `self` (but doesn't use it). For this to work, the `font_size_reset()` method must be redefined to access the `root` widget of the app:

```
class Restore():

    def font_size_reset(self):
        root = App.get_running_app().root  # get a reference to the app root widget
        root.ids.label.font_size = 16
        root.ids.but1.text = 'font_size\nEnlarge'
        root.ids.but1.color = 'white'
```

A slightly better approach would be to make the `font_size_reset()` method static, so that the meaningless argument is not needed. In this approach, the `Restore` class can be:

```
class Restore():
    @staticmethod
    def font_size_reset():
        root = App.get_running_app().root  # get a reference to the app root widget
        root.ids.label.font_size = 16
        root.ids.but1.text = 'font_size\nEnlarge'
        root.ids.but1.color = 'white'
```

and the corresponding `test3.kv`:

```
#: import Restore test3.Restore
BoxLayout:

    Button:
        id: but1
        text: 'font_size\nEnlarge'
        on_press: app.enlarge_text()
        markup: True

    Button:
        text: 'font_size\nRestore'
        on_press: Restore.font_size_reset()

    Label:
        id: label
        font_size: 16
        text: str(int(label.font_size))
```

Comment: Would you please explain the syntax of #:import Restore test3.Restore as I don't really understand what it's doing.  Your explanation of my problem is easy to follow and understand, thank you.

Comment: The `import` in the `kv` file is importing `test3.Restore`, which is the `Restore` class in the `test3.py` file, and assigning the name `Restore` to it. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#import-package).